# How to compile an XBlockExpression within a longer generated code

Tags: xtext

I have a DSL that includes blocks that need to be wrapped as methods returned inside an anonymous class created by the generated code. For example:

```
model {
    task {
        val x = 2*5;
        Math.pow(2, x)
    }
}
```

should compile to (note `task` becoming an instance of `Runnable`, with the body of the task becoming the body of the `Runnable.run()` method):

```java
import java.util.Collection;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MyFile {
  public Collection<Runnable> tasks() {
    ArrayList<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    tasks.add(getTask0());
    return tasks;
  }

  public static Runnable getTask0() {
    Runnable _runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        final int x = (2 * 5);
        Math.pow(2, x);
      }
    }
    return _runnable;
  }
}
```

Following the discussion in [this question](/q/34434562/552683), I was able to get this particular example to work. ([Github repo](https://github.com/cubranic/xblockexpression-in-templates) includes unit tests.) But I had to do it by representing the Task element in the grammar as a sequence of `XExpression`s ([source](https://github.com/cubranic/xblockexpression-in-templates/blob/03820e6377c374d556f22d6ad769523875919998/org.xtext.example.taskdsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/TaskDsl.xtext#L13)), which my `XbaseCompiler` subclass had to iterate over ([source](https://github.com/cubranic/xblockexpression-in-templates/blob/03820e6377c374d556f22d6ad769523875919998/org.xtext.example.taskdsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/jvmmodel/TaskDslCompiler.xtend#L23)).

Instead, it would have been nice to be able to just have `Task` contain an `XBlockExpression` in a property `action`, and then in the compiler just do `doInternalToJavaStatement(expr.action, it, isReferenced)`. My sense is that this is really the "right" solution in my case, but when I tried it, this would result in an empty body of the generated `run` method, as if the block was not processed at all. What's going on, and am I missing some required bits of setup/wiring things together/bindings that are necessary for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

you ususally try to avoid that by using a better inference strategy e.g.

Grammar

```
Model:
    {Model}"model" "{"
        vars+=Variable*
        tasks+=Task*
    "}"
    ;

Variable:
    "var" name=ID ":" type=JvmParameterizedTypeReference
;   

Task:
    {Task} "task" content=XBlockExpression
;
```

Inferrer

```
class MyDslJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

    @Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder

    def dispatch void infer(Model element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(element.toClass("test.Model2")) [
            for (v : element.vars) {
                members+=v.toField(v.name, v.type.cloneWithProxies) [

                ]
            }

            var i = 0;
            for (t : element.tasks) {
                val doRunName = "doRun"+i
                members += t.toMethod("task"+i, Runnable.typeRef()) [
                    body = '''
                    return new «Runnable» () {
                        public void run() {
                            «doRunName»();
                        }
                    };
                    '''
                ]
                members += t.toMethod(doRunName, Void.TYPE.typeRef()) [
                    body = t.content
                ]
                i = i + 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and that basically is it.

you may follow https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481992

If you really want to adapt the xbase typesystem that may be a lot more of work e.g. (just covering a minimal case)

Grammar

```
Model:
    {Model}"model" "{"
        vars+=Variable*
        tasks+=Task*
    "}"
    ;

Variable:
    "var" name=ID ":" type=JvmParameterizedTypeReference
;   

Task:
    {Task} "task" content=XTaskContent
;

XTaskContent returns xbase::XExpression:
    {XTaskContent} block=XBlockExpression
;
```

Inferrer

```
class MyDslJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

    @Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder

    def dispatch void infer(Model element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(element.toClass("test.Model")) [
            for (v : element.vars) {
                members+=v.toField(v.name, v.type.cloneWithProxies) [

                ]
            }

            var i = 0;
            for (t : element.tasks) {
                members += t.toMethod("task"+i, Runnable.typeRef()) [
                    body = t.content
                ]
                i = i + 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Type Computer

```
class MyDslTypeComputer extends XbaseTypeComputer {

    override computeTypes(XExpression expression, ITypeComputationState state) {
        if (expression instanceof XTaskContent) {
            _computeTypes(expression as XTaskContent, state);
        } else {
            super.computeTypes(expression, state)
        }
    }

    protected def void _computeTypes(XTaskContent object, ITypeComputationState state) {
        state.withExpectation(getPrimitiveVoid(state)).computeTypes(object.block)
        state.acceptActualType(getTypeForName(Runnable, state), ConformanceFlags.CHECKED_SUCCESS )
    }

}
```

Compiler

```
class MyDslCompiler extends XbaseCompiler {

    override protected internalToConvertedExpression(XExpression obj, ITreeAppendable appendable) {
        if (obj instanceof XTaskContent) {
            appendable.append("new ").append(Runnable).append("() {").newLine
            appendable.increaseIndentation
            appendable.append("public void run()").newLine
            reassignThisInClosure(appendable, null)
            internalToJavaStatement(obj.block, appendable, false)
            appendable.newLine
            appendable.decreaseIndentation
            appendable.newLine.append("}")
        } else {
            super.internalToConvertedExpression(obj, appendable)
        }
    }

}
```

Bindings

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    def Class<? extends ITypeComputer> bindITypeComputer() {
        return MyDslTypeComputer
    }
    def Class<? extends XbaseCompiler> bindXbaseCompiler() {
        return MyDslCompiler
    }

}
```

Comment: In my case, I really do want to have the user-provided block contained entirely within the `Runnable.run` method. The reason is that the `model` can also contain variables, which become the generated class's fields, and are passed as arguments to the `getTask*` methods. (See [example](https://github.com/cubranic/xblockexpression-in-templates/blob/64896f9b247e3707e2f08ad016da55dcf63f78fa/org.xtext.example.taskdsl.tests/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/tests/TaskDslGeneratorTest.xtend#L112).) This is important because of some Java optimizations I get for free in the rest of the system.

Comment: yes but even that points could be easily achived using the "Infer right stuff pattern" e.g. by passing the arguments as parameters to the doRun Method or by passing the argument holding class as parameter with name "it" to the doRun Method. or you use a real class instead of an anonymous one

Comment: When I use an anonymous `Runnable`, the class generated by the JVM will have as its fields *only* the variables from the enclosing environment that are actually used in the `run` method. That's a useful optimization that the rest of my application takes advantage of. Using one of your suggestions means that I will have to walk the block's syntax tree myself to look for these dependencies, duplicating (and possibly not 100% correctly) what the compiler already does.

Comment: i still dont get your point. can you please come up with the code you would want to generate that actually uses that feature ?

Comment: i have updated my example to show both approches side by side